# AngularJS watch $window.documet.visibilityState doesn't work instantly on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `AngularJs` version 1.4, I need to detect when user is not on the tab of the my app and when he comes back so I tried using $watch this way:

```
$rootScope.$watch(angular.bind($window, function(document){
    return this.document.visibilityState
}), function (n, o) {
    if (n === 'visible' && o == 'hidden') {
        console.log('Im back')
    }
})
```

The problem that when I go back to the tab it takes a lot of time until it activates the response function on change, something like 5 seconds.

Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try onfocus and onblur of window :

```
window.onblur = function() { console.log('blur'); }
window.onfocus = function() { console.log('focus'); }
```

It works with simple java script.
In angular you can try this

```
$window.onblur = function() { console.log('blur'); }
$window.onfocus = function() { console.log('focus'); }
```